# How does UEFI detect boot devices in partitions?

Tags: bios, uefi

How does UEFI detects boot devices ?

If I just install linux on some partition, say /dev/sda2, how does the uefi will be able to recognize it as boot entry ?

Does BIOS checks every partition ? How ?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? They are completely different in boot method. BIOS executes code in the MBR if disks that have a partition flagged as "Active & Bootable", UEFI is completely different except when in Legacy mode. Google actually can get you very detailed answers for each scenario. What issue are you trying to fix here or what is the problem?

Comment: I've fixed question for uefi only

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Plain PC **BIOS** does not understand partitions. It only reads sector 0 (the MBR), runs the initial bootcode found there (which has to be installed by the OS), and that bootcode *itself* has to parse the partition table.

(Not all MBR bootsectors perform this task the same way. The ones installed by Windows or Syslinux just search for a partition marked as 'active', while GRUB and LILO instead look for a configuration file at some hardcoded location. Some bootsectors only understand MBR, others can read GPT.)

So a BIOS boot menu will only have disks, *not* partitions – and the fancy boot menu that lists operating systems is shown by the OS bootloader (e.g. GRUB), not by BIOS. Searching for the OS kernel partition and starting the OS itself is also done by this bootloader, not by BIOS.

---

Unlike BIOS, **UEFI** firmware actually understands MBR and GPT partition tables. However, UEFI still does not recognize Linux or Windows partitions, and cannot directly start the OS from there.

Instead, the UEFI firmware only looks for a specific **"EFI system partition"**, a FAT32 partition that contains bootloader programs. The firmware also keeps a list of operating systems in the [NVRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory), and each installed OS adds its own entry there, pointing to its own `*.efi` file within the system partition.

For example, Windows always adds an entry titled "Windows Boot Manager" which points to the file "\EFI\Microsoft\Bootmfgw.efi", which is the Windows bootloader.

So the UEFI boot menu can have several types of boot entries:

1. Manually added entries stored in NVRAM – with a custom label and pointing to a specific file within the EFI system partition;
2. Automatically detected *disks* which have a `\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi` file within EFI system partition – these have no custom label, just "UEFI:" followed by the disk's model;
3. If enabled – disks which have a BIOS MBR (for booting in compatibility mode).

As you can see, UEFI firmware only uses one partition (the EFI system partition), but the rest (finding the OS kernel partition) is still done by the operating system's own bootloader.

Even in UEFI, graphical boot menus which let you choose the OS or kernel version are also usually shown by the OS bootloader – not by UEFI itself.

---

That said, the Linux bootloader still doesn't exactly know anything about the *root* partition. The Linux bootloader's main task is to find the kernel image (vmlinuz) and the initramfs archive, and to provide command-line options to the kernel – which contain the root partition's name in Linux syntax, such as `root=/dev/sda2` or `root=UUID=XYZ-ABC`.

Finally, once the Linux kernel is started, it will *itself* search for a partition matching the name provided, and will mount it on `/`. (This can be done either by the kernel internally, or by the initramfs if more flexibility is wanted.)

Comment: A very nice and clear answer!

Comment: Does setting partition type to EF00 somehow affects boot process?

Comment: @MaximKhokhryakov: It may affect option 2 (autodetection), though I'd need to re-check the [specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_10_Aug29.pdf); I _think_ the partition type was not really required. (Setting the correct partition type does help an OS find the right partition to _install_ things to, however.)